# Ошибка при линковке boost::thread

Tags: c++, многопоточность, boost, asio

Собрал boost версии 1.37. Хочу собрать программу.

Makefile

```
PROJECT = test
SOURCES = main.cpp Connection.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
INC = -I./boost/include
LIBS = -lboost_system-gcc46-1_37 -lboost_thread-gcc46-mt-1_37 -lpthread
LDFLAGS = -L./boost/lib 

test:
    g++ -c $(INC) $(SOURCES)
    g++ -lrt $(LDFLAGS) -o $(PROJECT) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)
    rm -f *.d *.o

clean:
    rm -f *.d *.o

.PHONY: clean
```

Connection.h

```
#define BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::system;

class Connection {
public:
    Connection(io_service& service);
private:
    ip::tcp::socket socket_;
};
```

Connection.cpp

```
#include "Connection.h"

Connection::Connection(io_service& service)
    : socket_(service)
{}
```

При сборке следующая ошибка

> g++ -c -I./boost/include main.cpp Connection.cpp g++ -lrt
>   -L./boost/lib  -o test main.o Connection.o -lboost_system-gcc46-1_37 '-lboost_thread-gcc46-mt-1_37 -lpthread Connection.o: In function
>   `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
>
> Connection.cpp(.text._ZN5boost6system10error_codeC2Ev[_ZN5boost6system10error_codeC5Ev]+0x17):
>   undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
>
> Connection.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
>
> Connection.cpp(.text._ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv[boost::asio::error::get_system_category()]+0x5):
>   undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make: *** [basler] Ошибка 1

Из за чего эта ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Забыли ещё одну библиотеку. "libboost_system-gcc46-mt-1_37" (а может без mt, ищите по boost_system).

Comment: так то она есть, пробовал и с mt и без

Comment: попробовал у себя (main пришлось сделать минимальным). Все заработало, только поправил одну строку

   LIBS = -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread

какой дистрибутив?

Comment: Boost качал отсюда http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_37_0.html

Comment: конечно же имелось ввиду дистрибутив ОСи.

Comment: OpenSuse 12.1

Comment: тогда у меня осталось только две идеи.

 - не установлены/плохо установелны девелоперские версии пакетов для буста.
 - так как буст установлен не с репозитарев, то он там есть "несоответствие" (например, буст 32 битный, а компилятор 64)

моя рекомендация - удалите вручную установленный буст и поставьте с репозитариев.